# Is it possible to set up readable names to addresses using Infura?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

In my application, I want to create readable names for eth addresses. Currently, I use my own node and it's easy to use:

```
WEB3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(NODE_NAME))
NS = ENS.fromWeb3(W3)

NS.setup_address(name=..., address=..., transact=...)
```

I would like to switch to Infura, but I am not sure how to use the same logic with it? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Why would it be different for Infura?

Comment: Also I recommend [checking alternative node providers to Infura](https://ethereumnodes.com/) that may provide a higher quality of service and lower cost.